# Is it possible to run an oracle container image in local machine without docker desktop?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, cloud, minikube, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I have oracle container images in Oracle Container Registry in OCI cloud. The image can be from anywhere.

I need to execute/run those images in my local machine but my requirement is I cannot use Docker Desktop currently.

I see there are a few alternatives are there like podman, rocket where I can run these images in the local machine.

I need to know from the experts the best way to run the images in the local machine without the Docker Desktop.

Advance Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Docker containers run natively in Windows Server 2016, Windows Server 2019 and Windows 10. These labs are based on the latest releases of Windows and Docker which provide the best experience for containerized Windows applications.

The minimum requirements are:

- Windows 10 Professional or Enterprise, with Windows update 1809 or
- Windows Server 2019

You can install a native Windows binary which allows you to develop and run Windows containers without Docker Desktop. For more information about running Windows containers on Windows Server in Getting Started with [Windows Containers](https://github.com/docker/labs/blob/master/windows/windows-containers/README.md).

Comment: I am using MAC. Is it possible on mac as well?

Comment: As the Oracle is very large in size and is very complex to handle and maintain on different systems like [MAC](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/mac/install/), therefore, its recommended to use the Docker mentioned system configurations for running the docker container on your system.
Follow the Link [How to Set Up Oracle Database with Docker](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OTglm9fVCL4)

Comment: @Arindam, Did my answer help to solve the issue? If yes, can you please accept the answer provided for the benefit of other community members who will face the same issue.

Comment: I think Docker will not be free anymore in the near future, maybe after 1+ month. Hence looking for an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

To answer this question it really depends on what sort of instances you're running within your tenancy to interact with Oracle Cloud Container Registry.  (You mention Oracle Container Registry in your question but that's actually the Oracle publishing platform for Oracle container images, but I think you mean the registry as a service in Oracle Cloud Infrastructure which is Oracle Cloud Container Registry.)

Most people that I know use Oracle Linux within OCI as it's the preferred OS for deploying instances.  As such, my answer is based on that.

If you're using Oracle Linux 7, then the native docker that you would install on your instances would not be Docker Desktop, but instead a version of the docker ecosystem built for Oracle Linux systems.  It's completely free to use (vs Docker Desktop).

If you're using Oracle Linux 8, then the native container client is podman which functions very much similarly to docker client, but some subtle differences.

In either case, you could choose to run other container runtimes, none of which would be Docker Desktop.